# Can a classic ASP page using xmlhttp make a JSON request?

Tags: json, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I am completely lost.  I am trying to post to an API on a remote server from a classic asp page that uses vbscript.  My code:

```
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "POST", vURL, false 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type","application/json"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept","application/json"
xmlhttp.send "email=asdf@hotmail.com&firstname=joe&lastname=smith"
vAnswer = xmlhttp.responseText
```

I receive a response that the request is not in the expected format. Tech support informs me that the API expects JSON in the post body.  Can I do this from server-side asp?

Answer (score 6):

```
'Create a function
Function ASPPostJSON(url)

'declare a variable
Dim objXmlHttp

Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'If the API needs userName and Password authentication then pass the values here
objXmlHttp.Open "POST", url, False, "User123", "pass123"
objXmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objXmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "ASP/3.0"

'send the json string to the API server
objXmlHttp.Send "{""TestId"": 012345,""Test1Id"": 123456,""Test123"": 37,""Type123"": ""Test_String"",""contact"": {""name"": ""FirstName LastName"",""Organization"": ""XYZ"",""phone"":""123456"",""emailAddress"": ""test@mail.com""}}"

'If objXmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
    ASPPostJSON = CStr(objXmlHttp.ResponseText)
'end if

'return the response from the API server
Response.write(ASPPostJSON)
Set objXmlHttp = Nothing

End Function

'call the function and pass the API URL
call ASPPostJSON("https://TheAPIUrl.com/")
```

Comment: Please improve formatting by indenting code with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Because I ran across this when effectively trying to solve the same issue -- in my case, POSTing from ASP Classic to the MailChimp 2.0 API -- I wanted to echo the helpfulness of the http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/ link, but also note something that was at least relevant in the case of MailChimp. I thought I could simply format a JSON-looking string and send that, but it didn't work. I had to create a JSON object using the methods in the aspjson library, and then use the jsString method in the send statement. So the code snippet (after appropriate declarations, includes, etc.) would look something like this:

```
Set objJSON = jsObject()
objJSON("apikey") = "MY API KEY"
Set objJSON("email") = jsObject()
objJSON("email")("email") = strEmail
Set objXMLhttp = Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXMLhttp.open "POST","https://mailchimpurl/2.0/helper/lists-for-email", false
objXMLhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type","application/json"
objXMLhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept","application/json"
objXMLhttp.send objJSON.jsString
strResponse = objXMLhttp.responseText
Set objXMLhttp = Nothing
```

Hope that helps someone else along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it should help you do what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

Good luck!

Comment: Bugget, I downloaded that earlier, but I don't see how it can be used to format a JSON request.  I will take another look.

Comment: @user1048348 That is exactly what it does look at the examples in the Wiki pages. However your answer might have been more helpful if you had included a small sample of code for the OP, rather than just a link.

Answer (score 1):

The request you are sending is ..... not JSON. Try use this as a validator: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). Chuck your JSON string into there and it will tell you if it's valid or not. In the case above: `email=asdf@hotmail.com&firstname=joe&lastname=smith`. It is most definitely not.

You can write JSON by hand, for example I would rewrite your query as follows:

`{"Email":"asdf@hotmail.com", "firstname":"joe", "lastname":"smith"}`

I hope that helps. Yes, there are libraries that can help you do this (ASPJSON is one of them) but to be honest I prefer writing them out myself (ASP is so unwieldy) or writing my own functions because I know that I can trust them. Here is an example piece of code I wrote in ASP that can make a JSON string from a Dictionary object. It can also have arrays inside the dictionary elements. Unfortunately it's not recursive so it can't do arrays of arrays or dictionaries of dictionaries ... but it works quiet well for simple inputs. Named json_encode after the PHP function.

```
Function json_encode(ByVal dic)
    ret = "{"
    If TypeName(dic) = "Dictionary" Then
        For each k in dic
            Select Case VarType(dic.Item(k))
                Case vbString
                    ret = ret & """" & k & """:""" & dic.Item(k) & ""","
                Case Else
                    If VarType(dic.Item(k)) > vbArray Then
                        ret = ret & """" & k & """:["
                        For x = 0 to Ubound(dic.Item(k), 1)
                            ret = ret & """" & dic.Item(k)(x) & ""","
                        Next
                        ret = Left(ret, Len(ret) - 1)   'Trim trailing comma
                        ret = ret & "],"
                    Else
                        ret = ret & """" & k & """:""" & dic.Item(k) & ""","
                    End If
            End Select
        Next
        ret = Left(ret, Len(ret) - 1)   'Trim trailing comma
    End If
    ret = ret & "}"
    json_encode = ret
End Function
```

Comment: In your example above you have written the JSON in square brackets.  This is invalid it should be curly braces e.g.  {"Email":"asdf@hotmail.com", "firstname":"joe", "lastname":"smith"}